# Creating a webservice client form the given XSDs

Tags: java, web-services, xsd, cxf

I am a newbie in web-service development. As part of my project I need to create a web-service client to access some kind of services. I am given a set of XSD files (There are multiple services exposed, and corresponding to each service a set of request and response XSDs - say like get country list there is a country-request and country-response XSD and for zip code based search there is zip-request and zip-response XSDs and so on).

I am thinking about generating corresponding WSDL files from XSDs using eclipse (I could find some related post in SOF and some tutorials) and then use CXF to generate client using CXF.

I am still learning but looking forward know whether I'm following the correct way of doing it.

Any suggestion would help me a lot.

Thanks in advance.

Dev